# kdb dbmaint to backfill data with existing data

Tags: kdb

I would like to use dbmaint package to add a column to all dates in hdb, and then backfill the column I add with the data from another existing column in the same table to all dates.

I just added a column to all dates with default value. How can I backfill the column with the data from another column? I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `copycol` function in `dbmaint.q` is what you are looking for. Please be aware that this function does not work for nested columns.

```
q)\l dbmaint.q
q)tables[]
`s#`depthsecond`quotessecond`tradessecond
q)tradessecond
date       sym  time                          src price size
------------------------------------------------------------
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:00.078000000 N   25.32 1634
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.419000000 O   25.35 1900
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.504000000 O   25.32 627
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.846000000 O   25.32 69
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:07.177000000 O   25.32 4821
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:07.373000000 O   25.35 2321
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:11.861000000 L   25.33 545

q)
q)copycol[`:hdb2;`tradessecond;`price;`price_new]
2018.08.13 17:14:55 copying price to price_new in `:hdb2/2018.07.16/tradessecond
2018.08.13 17:14:55 copying price to price_new in `:hdb2/2018.07.17/tradessecond
2018.08.13 17:14:55 copying price to price_new in `:hdb2/2018.07.18/tradessecond
q)\l hdb2
q)tradessecond
date       sym  time                          src price size price_new
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:00.078000000 N   25.32 1634 25.32
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.419000000 O   25.35 1900 25.35
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.504000000 O   25.32 627  25.32
2018.07.16 AAPL 2018.07.16D08:00:03.846000000 O   25.32 69   25.32
```

As you can see the `tradessecond` table now contains the `price_new` column. If you have a different case (nested columns or you do not want to copy the column as I showed in my example) you will have to do the update manually (reiterate through all the partitions, save the column down, update `.d` file and enumerate if necessary).

Answer (score 4):

As per Alex's solution - `copycol` will work if you want an exact duplicate of the existing column.

If you want to create a *derived* column from an existing column then you would also need to use the `fncol` function to apply a lambda to the column. For example to create a copy of a price column and then double all prices in the new column:

```
copycol[`:hdb;`table;`price;`price_new];
fncol[`:hdb;`table;`price_new;{2*x}];
```

The lambda doesn't contain any other info from the table, it only contains the values from the column being modified.

If however your derived column was more advanced and required data from two or more columns from the table then you would need to create some modifications to the vanilla dbmaint package as follows:

Create a new version of fncol which passes the current directory path into the function

```
fncol2:{[dbdir;table;col;fn]
 {fn1col[z;x;y@z]}[col;fn;]each allpaths[dbdir;table];};
```

Then within your lambda you can pull in other columns as required, for example if you wanted to add two price columns:

```
{[path;vector] vector + get ` sv path,`otherPriceCol}
```

So overall your copy and modify command would be:

```
copycol[`:hdb;`table;`price;`price_new];
fncol2[`:hdb;`table;`price_new;{[path;vector] vector + get ` sv path,`otherPriceCol}];
```